# edit config file in stanford pos tagger

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp, maxent

i have tagged a simple sentence and this is my code:

```
package tagger;

import edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger;

public class myTag {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    MaxentTagger tagger = new MaxentTagger("D:/tagger/english-bidirectional-distsim.tagger");


    String sample = "i go to school by bus";

    String tagged = tagger.tagString(sample);

    System.out.println(tagged);
}

}
```

this is the output:

```
    Reading POS tagger model from D:/tagger/english-bidirectional-distsim.tagger    ... done [3.0 sec].
i_LS go_VB to_TO school_NN by_IN bus_NN
```

after editing the properties file it doesn't have any effect at all.
for example i have changed the tag separator to ( * ) but in the output it still prints ( _ ).

how could i use the model config file in eclipse?

Comment: Note that the bidirectional model [is not generally the best model to use in real-world applications](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/pos-tagger-faq.shtml#h). There are other models that sacrifice a small amount of accuracy for a substantial increase in speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load Properties file and pass it to the constructor of MaxEnt, something like this:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(new FileReader("path/to/properties"));
MaxentTagger tagger = new MaxentTagger("D:/tagger/english-bidirectional-distsim.tagger", props);
```

You can also set properties in `props` object directly:

```
props.setProperty("tagSeparator", "*");
```

NB: if you use the original properties file and it fails with exception like

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /u/nl
p/data/pos_tags_are_useless/egw4-reut.512.clusters (No such file or directory)
```

then remove `arch` and `trainFile` attributes.

Comment: could you please explain more about the first solution>>VM arguments?

Comment: What is it exactly to be explained?

Comment: the second solution works fine but i want to change multiple parameters in properties file so in this case the first solution is better.the question is how to pass the properties file as arguments to program?

Comment: I've edited sample code (and checked it); try it now.

Comment: I think you should create another question and explain your problem in detail. In particular, what is the expected result, the actual one (seems to be presented here) and steps-to-reproduce. Currently I don't get your problem.

Comment: this is the new question,tahnks.[link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29443556/xml-format-in-stanford-pos-tagger)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing a java code for this, you can use the bash file which comes in the downloaded ZIP file.
After extracting the postagger's ZIP file, edit the following bash file:

> stanford-postagger.sh

It should have the following line:

```
java -mx300m -cp 'stanford-postagger.jar:lib/*' edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger -model $1 -textFile $2
```

Add a parameter called "**-tagSeparator [YourTag]**" after **"-model $1"**:

```
java -mx300m -cp 'stanford-postagger.jar:lib/*' edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger -model $1 -tagSeparator * -textFile $2
```

To run it (Make sure necessary permissions are given):

```
./stanford-postagger.sh models/model_name.tagger in_filename > out_filename
```

Voilà!