# xml format in stanford pos tagger

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, nlp, stanford-nlp

i have tagged 20 sentences and this is my code:

```
public class myTag {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Properties props = new Properties();

    try {
        props.load(new FileReader("D:/tagger/english-bidirectional-distsim.tagger.props"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    MaxentTagger tagger = new MaxentTagger("D:/tagger/english-bidirectional-distsim.tagger",props);
    
    //==================================================================================================
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Users/chelsea/Desktop/EN/EN.txt")))
    {

        String sCurrentLine;

        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            
            String tagged = tagger.tagString(sCurrentLine);
            System.out.println(tagged);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
}

}
```

this is the output:

[image: img]

as you can see in sentence node it has a Id attribute and here it's constantly=0 which it should not be.i expect the value=0,1,2,3,4,...
i don't understand what is wrong with my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stanford POS tagger (strictly speaking, sentence splitter that is applied before POS annotator) generates ids for sentences per input text.
So, you ask `tagger` to tag `sCurrentLine` consisting of one sentence, this text is split into sentences - actually, just one, with id = 0; then you ask to tag another text - `sCurrentLine` from the next iteration - and it again is the only sentence and thereby it is the first sentence with id = 0; and so on.

Thus, if you want correct ids, firstly create the whole text, then pass it to `tagger`. However, if your input text is already split by sentences, it'll be better to leave things as they are (and generate ids by yourself in the loop, if you need them).