# Change pos tag separator in Stanford NLP Maxent Tagger using C#

Tags: c#, stanford-nlp, pos-tagger

I have the Stanford POS tagging working with C# by following the instructions on this page https://sergey-tihon.github.io/Stanford.NLP.NET/StanfordPOSTagger.html

The results are:

```
A/DT Part-Of-Speech/NNP Tagger/NNP -LRB-/-LRB- POS/NNP Tagger/ (…etc…)
```

I would like to change the tag separator from the slash character (/) to an underscore (_).

I have looked in the properties file

wsj-0-18-bidirectional-distsim.tagger.props

and it already has the line: tagSeparator = _

According to the answer on this page [edit config file in stanford pos tagger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29429137/edit-config-file-in-stanford-pos-tagger)
 and the example on this page https://sergey-tihon.github.io/Stanford.NLP.NET/StanfordCoreNLP.html
 it seems that I should be able to change the tagger's properties by adding the following code:

```
var props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("tagSeparator", "_");
```

However this approach does not work as the first line will not compile, giving the syntax error:

'Properties' is a namespace but is used like a type

I have not found a way to change the separator to an underscore.

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try rewriting

```
var props = new Properties();
```

as

```
var props = new java.util.Properties();
```

and it should work.